# installing google-chrome gives me error

Tags: centos, software-installation, chrome

When I run the following command

```
sudo yum install -y ruby ruby-devel gcc xorg-x11-server-Xvfb google-chrome-stable
```

on a centos 6 server

I get the following error:

```
 Package: google-chrome-stable-51.0.2704.63-1.x86_64 (google-chrome)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.18)(64bit)
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess you run into the problem that Google (and others) simply use more recent build systems which create backwards-incompatible binaries for systems like centos 6.

Determine what versions of GLIBCXX are supported on your maschine with e.g.:

`strings /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBC`

Does GLIBCXX_3.4.18 show up?

[1] Read a full explanation on e.g. http://chrome.richardlloyd.org.uk/ and how to handle that situation.

Comment: Just to update, the site in the link is no more working. Also, the script no more works for versions 59+. The answer is no longer relevant.

Answer (score 0):

---

GLIBCXX means : G .. LIBC++ . ( Like CXX = g++ )

"gcc-4.8.x" : `GLIBCXX_3.4.18` is an object in libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6.0.18 : Please see $ `objdump -x /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX_3.4`

I don't think we can find a `libstdc++.so.6.0.18` that is compiled with glibc-2.12 . Most gcc-4.8 are compiled with a much later glibc.

Solution : Build gcc-4.8.5, and you get a usable `libstdc++.so.6.0.18`.

---